# How can i import multiple PDF as Layer in Adobe Acrobat Pro?

Tags: layers, adobe-acrobat

I have about 50 PDFs of one sheet each that I want to import as layers in another PDF with Adobe Acrobat Pro. As far as I can see, you can only import one at a time. Is there a way to make it more automatic?
[image]